# HTML5 video - disable fullscreen only

Tags: html, video

I am using the video tag for my page, and I am trying to exclude the fullscreen from the controls.

I see that the "controls" in general is only a true/false statement, but i am looking for a way to disable the fullscreen option from the video.

I could do controls false and use autoplay the video - Then i have no controls - and the video will just play.. - but i think this is too drastic a "solution".

So what kind of solution can be done to achieve what i am looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controls` is a binary state, you either have what the browser provides or you have nothing.

If you don't want the browser to provide a full screen control but still want a UI, then you'll need to turn controls off and implement your own UI with JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, but i can't seem to find the call i need for controlling the video. Where do i find this information ?

Comment: "The" call? You need lots. Seek, play and pause at the very least. The media element definition covers most of it: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#htmlmediaelement

Answer (score 15):

For browsers that incorporate a shadow DOM (e.g. newest version of Chrome), you can still use the default controls, but hide the fullscreen button.

Just be sure to include the following in your CSS:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
{
        display: none !important;
}
```

As shadow DOM manipulation like this becomes more commonplace, more browsers will hopefully support it. Until then, stick to making custom controls or putting the video within an `iframe` as long as your `src` points to an html file with a `video` tag in it, and you specify `allowfullscreen="false"`for the `iframe`.